# Iterating through non uniform of array of objects with Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

Suppose I have the following data:

```
sampleData = [{'artist': 'John', 'id': 1}, {'artist': 'John', 'id': 2},
{'artist': 'Tim', 'id': 3}, {'artist': 'Jimmy', 'id': 4}, {'venue': 'Rock club', 'id':1}, {'venue': 'Rock club', 'id': 2}, {'venue': 'Tonys', 'id': 3}]
```

This data can be found in my controller and will be non-changing. What I want to do is construct two nested lists within a main `<ul>`.

Given I have the following input where where a user types 'J' or 'j':

```
<input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Filter by">
```

This is what I would like to have rendered using ng-repeat(unless I don't have to use ng-repeat):

```
<ul>
  <h1>artist</h1>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>John (There are two 2 Johns)</li>
      <li>Jimmy</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
    <h1>Venue</h1>
      <li>Jock Club (There are two 2 Jock Club)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Initially, I attempted to write a customer filter that took in the results from the filtered list and manipulated the data. Angular wasn't happy with my filter because I was modifying the original data too much and so I was receiving an infinite digest loop. So now I am back at square one trying to decide if this is best done with a directive or filter. I suspect that I need to restructure my data in my controller or in a directive to get my intended outcome. Again, my intended outcome would be a filtered  with artist and venue sublists of `sampleData` that is based on what a user is typing. Updating in a real time is ideal.

Comment: If you can, restructure your data to have an array of venues and a separate array of artists. Something like this: {artists: [{name: 'Johnny', ...}, {name: 'Jimmy', ...}], venues: [{name: 'Jock Club', ...}, {...}]}

Comment: This is actually exactly how I restructured my data except I did it with a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to restructure your data, it can be achieved by having functions in your controller that use a filter to get only the items you want for each ng-repeat:

In controller:

```
var sampleData = [...];
$scope.query = '';

$scope.getArtists = function () {
   return $filter('filter')(sampleData, function (item) {
       return item.hasOwnProperty('artist') && item.artist.indexOf($scope.query) > -1; 
   });
};

$scope.getVenues = function () {
   return $filter('filter')(sampleData, function (item) {
       return item.hasOwnProperty('venue') && item.venue.indexOf($scope.query) > -1;  
   });
};
```

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Filter by">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="artist in getArtists()"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="venue in getVenues()"></li>
</ul>
```

### ----------

However, it is probably better to restructure your data up front, so that you are able to iterate through venues and artists using a single function more efficiently:

In controller:

```
var sampleData = [...];
$scope.query = '';
$scope.artists = [];
$scope.venues = [];

angular.forEach(sampleData, function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('artist') {
        $scope.artists.push({
            id: item.id,
            name: item.artist
        });
    });
    else if (item.hasOwnProperty('venue') {
        $scope.venues.push({
            id: item.id,
            name: item.venue
        });
    });
});

$scope.getMatching = function (items, query) {
    return $filter('filter')(items, function (item) {
        return (item.name.indexOf(query) > -1); 
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Filter by">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="artist in getMatching(artists, query)"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="venue in getMatching(venues, query)"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome! How could I go about accessing the length of items in the data that meet the search query?

Comment: I misunderstood your question to begin with, and have edited so it should cope with the search query correctly. I also added a version that restructures the data too, so it's more efficient.